# Mobile js framework that implements MVP design pattern

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I have to develop a mobile web application that runs in a single HTML file. I have used before GWT and found that MVP framework is really a very good choice for this kind of frameworks.

Using GWT for mobile is not a very good idea because debugging and testing process is too slow. So Is there any alternative  for GWT_MVP architecture that contains these components : 
- Event Bus
- Activity (View)
- Presenter
- Model

And ideally a way to render model data into html components.
Can you point me for something please ?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't specifically have to be MVP..

I would guess most of the time Dojo is used, and has all necessary building blocks to accomplish this. I'm looking for best practises myself on how to do this ([How to best apply an MVC architecture in dojo mobile (custom controllers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171817/how-to-best-apply-an-mvc-architecture-in-dojo-mobile-custom-controllers)).

- Dojox.app MVC framework (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/app.html)
  Seems it is being preferred in a lot of cases nowadays.
- Custom Dojo widgets are able to follow a nice MVC pattern: good tutorial http://www.dojomonk.com/2013/05/dojo-for-jquery-developers.html
- Backbone supports the MVP pattern as far as I known, here is a tutorial of a Worklight application using backbone.js: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/building_mvc_applications_with_ibm_worklight_and_backbone_js?lang=en

Hope this helps.